# Can't share VPN connection on Mac

Tags: network, vpn, internet-sharing

I'm trying to share my VPN internet connection from Wi-Fi to ethernet (or vice-versa, doesn't really matter) on a Mac.

I was able to share the non-VPN connection but when I connect to the VPN it stops working.

Instead of selecting "Wi-Fi" in the "Share you connection from" dropdown, I selected the VPN connection like it's supposed to be. I've tried two different VPN services, *Free VPN* and *Speedify*:

[image]

I've seen some posts of people having this problem but in their case they had created the VPN connection themselves, so they had a check-box to "route all traffic" or something like that - but in my case the VPN apps created the connections and these are the only preferences that show up for me:

[image]

I followed the steps provided by the [Speedify support page](https://support.speedify.com/article/768-how-can-i-share-my-speedify-connection-to-my-other-wi-fi-devices-on-mac), which indicates sharing the VPN connection was supposed to be supported by this service.

I just want to be able to share a free VPN service from my Mac to another computer. Any VPN service, as long as it's free. How to investigate what's causing the problem?

I'm using Catalina and a 16" 2019 MB Pro.

Disclaimer: this is a [crosspost from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/qypgnj/cant_share_vpn_connection_on_mac/), I posted here after getting nothing there. I'm going to keep all posts updated with eventual answers I get.